# If mouse click triggered an event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a "Auto Mouse Click" project. This project is for a specific software so i want to explain my question deeply (c# and winform is used):

The software has "a button" that becomes enable after a while (after finishing some operations).

I created a mini-software which leads the mouse on "that button" and clicks on it. My program does it in every 5 seconds.

In 10 minutes time period "that button" becomes enable (for example) 7 times (it may change) but my program triggers click event 120 times (10min * 60sec/5sec).

Here is the question:
How can i detect if my auto click event fired "the button" when it was enabled.

If i couldnt explain my question, please enrich it with ur demands.

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: When launch `Click` event of "that button" manually, than it is doesn't matter is it enabled or not. Shoe how you mini software make a "Click" on button...

Comment: I suppose you do not have access to the button control because it is part of a third party software. What happens when that button is clicked? You should capture the event somehow and count them.

Comment: U r right FeliceM but the point is: i dont know how to capture the event.